# Overstay France Schengen visa by one day

Tags: schengen, france, overstaying

I made travel arrangements to travel to France between July 27 and August 10 with my family. I received a Schengen visa from the consulate of France from July 27 to August 10 for myself and my spouse, while my two children (12 and 17) received their visas from July 26 to August 9.

When I checked with the consulate, they told me it's not a problem if they stayed one additional day since they are with their parents. Is that normal?

Comment: No, it is not normal.

Comment: It seems an excuse for an error (off by one arrival and departure dates).

Comment: No, the consulate should correct these visas. DO NOT OVERSTAY.

Comment: It's not normal, you're not supposed to stay longer than your visa allows and the consulate presumably made a mistake when they issued it. Recommended practice (from the EU Commission) is even to add a few days to the validity period beyond the intended dates of travel. That said, while technically illegal, it's extremely unlikely that leaving on the next day will be a problem, at least in France, which is probably what the consulate tried to convey.

Comment: @DavidRicherby agreed, but I thought the response covers all the bases... so many questions are essentially answered in comments, which are not elevated to answers, and OP does the hit-and-run ... never returning after asking the question.

Comment: @Giorgio Re-reading, I agree.